# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 VSSDK Extensibility

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility, vssdk

This is the first time I am trying to create a Visual Studio extension.
I installed Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) and after that I installed the Extensibility Tools (Features / Common Tools / Visual Studio Extensibility Tools Update 1).

However, when I try to create a new project, it does not show me the required templates (VSIX, etc.), instead I see 'Install Visual Studio Extensibility Tools' option. I have tried installing again, but still I am not able to see the templates.

Is there anything in addition to the steps above that I need to do to be able to start using the Extensibility tools?

Comment: When you install Update 3, the setup should show a "Visual Studio Extensibility Tools Update 3" checkbox. Go to Control Panel, Program and Features,  Visual Studio 2015, Change, and select that checkbox.

Comment: I did that ... But it wasn't showing update 3, instead it was showing update 2